# Every theory with global SUSY is a free boson?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, topological-field-theory

I'm reading this (review?) article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157391901175 on topological field theories.

In section 3.2 (page 142) they seem to be claiming that for any theory with global SUSY there is a "nicolai map" which allows you to reexpress the partion function as that corresponding to a free boson. Am I misunderstanding this? Is global SUSY such a strong restriction that everything just ends up being equally well expressed as a free boson? If so, how are theories with SUSY any interesting if they're all free bosons.

Comment: Maybe this mean that some SUSY theories is topological? Few years ago people study partition function for different SUSY theories using **supersymmetric location**, and partition function localized on fixed point, where you need calculate only determinant for free theory.